# How can I run jupyter notebook from my virtual environment?

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, nomachine-nx, virtual-environment

I have created a virtual environment with Python3.3 which I need to interface with Siemens NX. 
    conda create -n nxve python=3.3 anaconda

I wan to run jupyter notebook from this virtual environment. When I try to install it, I'm getting version conflicts.

```
activate nxev
conda install jupyter
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in 
conflict:
  - jupyter -> ipykernel -> jupyter_client -> jupyter_core -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.3*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

How an I get jupyter notebook installed in this virtual environment? Alternatively, is it possible to run the virtual environment kernel from the root installation of jupyter notebook?

Comment: You can try to install just `ipykernel`, which should install a kernel that you can use from the root environment's install of `notebook`. However, why are you installing all of anaconda into this new environment? Why not just `conda create -n nxve python=3.3` and then install only the packages you need? I suspect that is causing some errors, if any of the dependencies for `jupyter` aren't packaged for Python 3.3

Answer (score 0):

The Jupyter stack often spawns other processes. My guess is that when you run python on the command line it will resolve to python 2.7. Try setting an alias:

```
alias python=python3
```

Also make sure that your PATH and PYTHONPATH variables are not pointing to anything python2 related.